# I got compilation error when trying to build the example codes

Tags: c++, cmake, c++-actor-framework

I have encountered this error after cmake then make. I have installed all dependencies as configuration..thanks

```
ME664JA-no-MacBook-Pro:examples ME664JA$ make
    [  0%] Built target all_examples
    [  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/curl_fuse.dir/curl/curl_fuse.cpp.o
    In file included from /Users/ME664JA/Projects/actor-framework/examples/curl/curl_fuse.cpp:45:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/all.hpp:25:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/sec.hpp:27:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/error.hpp:27:
    /usr/local/include/caf/fwd.hpp:111:12: error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
    enum class atom_value : uint64_t;
               ^
    /usr/local/include/caf/fwd.hpp:111:23: error: expected unqualified-id
    enum class atom_value : uint64_t;
                          ^
    In file included from /Users/ME664JA/Projects/actor-framework/examples/curl/curl_fuse.cpp:45:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/all.hpp:25:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/sec.hpp:27:
    In file included from /usr/local/include/caf/error.hpp:28:
    In file included from /us`enter code here`r/local/include/caf/atom.hpp:27:
    /usr/local/include/caf/detail/atom_val.hpp:29:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
    constexpr unsigned char encoding_table[] = {
    ^
    /usr/local/include/caf/detail/atom_val.hpp:29:11: error: expected unqualified-id
    constexpr unsigned char encoding_table[] = {
```

Comment: It might help to mention which compiler exactly was producing these messages (`make` should provide the executable when pressed, the compiler should have "debug options", too) and include the code from `/usr/local/include/caf/fwd.hpp` around line 111, too (you might need to inspect the _preprocessed_ code).

Comment: did you enable c++11 or c++14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ Actor Framework is written by C++11, Add one of those line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

or

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Comment: thanks, it works and now I get another error with linking.

Comment: @user3466948 that's another question

Comment: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [curl_fuse] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/curl_fuse.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

You have any ideas about this ?

Comment: missing library in link step

Comment: See [Cmake finds library but does not find symbols](//stackoverflow.com/q/23250233) and  [CMake link to external library](//stackoverflow.com/q/8774593)

Answer (score 0):

this example works for me

```
project(projectCAF)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CAF_INCLUDE_ALL /usr/local/include/caf)

include_directories(${CAF_INCLUDE_ALL})
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)


macro(add executable folder source)
  add_executable(${executable} ${folder}/${source}.cpp )

  target_link_libraries(${executable} "libcaf_core.so")
endmacro()

add(one . hello)
```